# how to find "illegal literal map"

Tags: angular6

I am in the process of migrating an application to Angular 6 from Angular 5. at this point I believe I have most issues sorted out and when building with `ng serve` or `ng build main` it builds as expected. however when building as `ng build --prod main` I get the below error

```
ERROR in : Error: Illegal State: literal maps should have been converted into functions
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitLiteralMap (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15824:19)
    at LiteralMap.visit (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:3483:28)
    at ASTWithSource.visit (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:3598:29)
    at convertPropertyBinding (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15626:52)
    at createHostBindingsFunction (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20068:39)
    at baseDirectiveFields (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19754:43)
    at compileComponentFromMetadata (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19793:29)
    at compileComponentFromRender2 (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19878:19)
    at /workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21551:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._compilePartialModule (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21527:24)
    at /workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21509:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler.emitAllPartialModules (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21509:19)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._emitRender3 (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:252:41)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (/workspace/tarnished-lamp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:235:59)
```

I have two questions from this

1. What does this Error actually mean
2. How do I find it and correct it

Comment: Have you solved in the meanwhile?

Comment: I haven't looked at this recently, I'll be coming back to it shortly I hope

Comment: I got it migrating from angular 6 to angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from angular 6.0 to 7.0, I enabled ivy compiler and I got the same error.
Disabling ivy option, AOT build works again.